# Uniqueness of tangent spaces

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

**Definition.** Let $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a locally Euclidean subset. Say it has a tangent space at $p\in X$ if there exists a linear subspace $V\leq \mathbb R^n$ of dimension $\dim_p X$ satisfying the following condition.

There exists a neighborhood $U\subset X$ of $p$ in $X$ for which
$$\lim_{\substack{h\to 0\\\text{in }U-p}}\frac{\|\pi_{V^\perp}(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0.$$ Here $U-p$ is the neighborhood of the origin in $X-p$ obtained by translation of $U$ by $(-p)\in  X\subset\mathbb R^n$.

---

Is $V\leq \mathbb R^n$ unique?

The usual argument for the uniqueness of the derivative of a map on an *open* subset of Euclidean spaces relies on convexity of open balls, so is not applicable here.

Comment: What is the definition of locally euclidean?

Comment: @JohnMa locally homeomorphic to some Euclidean space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $X\subseteq \mathbb R^3$ be the graph of the function $\sqrt{\|\cdot\|}:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R,$ i.e. $\{(x,y,\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2})\}.$ This is the surface of revolution of a cusp. Since $X$ is a graph, it is $2$-dimensional topological manifold. At $p=(0,0,0),$ any vector space $V$ containing $(0,0,1)$ satisfies your condition; in little-o notation, $x=o(x^{1/4})$ and $y=o(y^{1/4})$ near zero, so $h=(x,y,\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2})=(0,0,\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2})+o(\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}),$ so the projection onto the orthogonal complement of a space containing $(0,0,1)$ will be negligible compared to $\|h\|.$

You might be interested in the ["contingent cone"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContingentCone.html) - I think your $V$ can be taken to be any vector space containing the contingent cone.

Comment: Dear Dap, thank you for the elegant counterexample. Will anything change if we ask that the orthogonal projection be locally injective at $p$? I am hoping this will ensure uniqueness.

Comment: @Arrow: since $\dim(V^\perp)=n-\dim(V),$ we need $n\geq 2\dim(V).$ If you embed my $X$ in $\mathbb R^4$ by $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y,z,0),$ then take $V$ to be $\{(0,0,z,t)\},$ then the projection to the complement is $(x,y,z,t)\mapsto (x,y,0,0),$ which is injective on $X.$

Comment: So the "correct" condition is simply to ask the contingent cone to be a vector space?

Comment: @Arrow: first: did you mean the projection to $V$ is locally injective? I assumed $V^\perp$ in my last comment. $V$ would make more sense, and I don't know if that's true or not. I think if the contingent cone spans a space of dimension $\dim_p(X),$ then $V$ is uniquely determined by the condition $\dim(V)=\dim_p(X).$ But I haven't thought it through carefully.

Comment: Dear Dap, I did mean the projection to $V$. This is really the heart of my question (I initially asked without this condition but I am only interested in the case it holds). I can ask this as a separate question, but I would much appreciate your help! (Hopefully local injectivity does indeed give uniqueness and we can avoid mentioning the tangent cone.)

Comment: @Arrow: I thought about it for a few minutes and don't know the answer 

Comment: I created [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72302/room-for-arrow-and-dap) if you're interested :) If not, thanks again.